# automatically create a folder and copy files on installation

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to solve this problem.

Is it possible when installing a Joomla 2.5 plugin to automatically create a folder and copy some files into it? The folder should be created under images (joomla default images folder) /images/ and some files copied to there when the user installs the plugin.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You firstly need to add the following code to your XML file:

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

Then create a file called **script.php** and add the following code to it:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class com_helloWorldInstallerScript {

    function install($parent) {

        jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

        //change this to the name of the folder you want to create
        $newfolder = 'myfolder';

        if(JFolder::create(JUri::root() . 'images/' . $newfolder)) {        
            //duplicate the line below as many times as you want for each file you want to move
            JFile::move(JUri::root() . 'plugins/plugin_name/image.png', JUri::root() . 'images/' . $newfolder);
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. When installing got this error JFolder::create: Path not in open_basedir paths Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: I wrote it quickly so will test it later on tonight when I have time

Comment: by chance have you take a look on this? Thanks